# Is there a way to validate a zip code using Twilio functions feature?

Tags: twilio

Trying to find a way to have a studio automated survey flow, and after a user input of 5 integers the flow would call a function that validates a zip code. Is there a way to do this in Twilio functions? If not are there serverless alternatives?

Comment: Twilio Functions runs JavaScript. Did you have a particular way you want to validate if the zip code is accurate using JavaScript?

Comment: You'll have to make a request to a third party API, something like Ziptastic (https://www.getziptastic.com/faq). They have a free (version 2) tier, 100 requests every 24 hours.

Comment: No particular way, just confused on specifically the return in Twilio Functions if I'm calling it in Studio.